# How to filter a SQL column by a value e.g -1 and join the table to another table

Tags: sql

I have 2 SQL tables `clients` and `historic_contact`. I want to join the tables together however `historic_contact` has a column in which I want to use data with -1 in the last column pre_campaign

```
SELECT 
    clients.id, clients.age, clients.job, clients.marital_status,
    clients.education, clients.credit_in_default,
    historic_contact.contact_type, historic_contact.duration,
    historic_contact.count, historic_contact.pre_campaign
FROM 
    clients 
JOIN 
    historic_contact ON clients.id = historic_contact.client_id
```

This returns all data in the table and not data with -1 in the `pre_campaign` column after joining the two tables

Comment: Please post your table structures, sample data, and expected outcome. Also, what RDMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

use a where condition with `historic_contact.pre_campaign=-1`

```
SELECT 
clients.id,clients.age,clients.job,clients.marital_status,clients.education,clients.credit_in_default,
historic_contact.contact_type,historic_contact.duration,
historic_contact.count,historic_contact.pre_campaign
FROM clients JOIN historic_contact ON clients.id = historic_contact.client_id
    where historic_contact.pre_campaign=-1
```